# How to analyze a 2x3 design in which one level doesn't differ on one of the factors?

Tags: anova, statistical-power

I have a 2x3 factorial design for my experiment: 3 levels of information given to participants (None, Moderate, Extreme), and 2 levels of time that the information focuses on (2050 or 2100), for those who received information.

I'm curious about how to deal with the fact that my control group, receiving no information, basically does not differ on the Time factor. I'm a little worried that it reduces the power of my design to detect differences in the groups who did receive different (2050 or 2100) information.

What's the best way to approach this? Should I instead do a 2 (Moderate, Extreme) x 2 (2050, 2100) design, essentially excluding the control group? If so, what test should I do to then compare the control group to those who received different levels of information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One strategy would be to see your design as containing 5 groups, which we could label:

```
C, M2050, M2100, E2050, E2100
```

You could then set up various planned contrasts that examine questions of interest.

Here are some example contrast weights for testing various research questions:

```
C    M2050   M2100  E2050  E2100  Comparison
+4   -1      -1     -1     -1     Control versus other
0    +1      +1     -1     -1     Moderate versus extreme
0    +1      -1     +1     -1     2050 versus 2100
```

You could achieve something similar, by first testing whether control is different to the average of the other four groups and then performing the $2\times2$ ANOVA omitting the control group. The default tests in the $2\times2$ are likely to correspond to many of the planned comparisons you would do anyway (i.e., M versus E, 2050 versus 2010, and the interaction between `amount` and `duration`). 
However, the contrast approach might be slightly more powerful because your error variance may be smaller (its based on deviations from the four non-control group means rather than one overall non-control mean).

In previous questions, you've asked about SPSS, so here's an example of testing a contrast using [`GLM` in SPSS](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/contrast.htm). And here's a [lecture on how to do it using R](http://faculty.smu.edu/kyler/courses/7311/planned_4up.pdf).

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you very much. I'm just a little confused by the SPSS example. For the two way ANOVA they list a special contrast such as (1 1 1 -3). I.e. only 4 levels, the number of levels of their B factor, while they have 8 groups from the 2x4 design. I'll keep searching for how to translate to my scenario, but if you know it would be a great help.

Comment: I suppose that `/contrast(b)=special (0 0 1 -1).` means that the contrast is performed on the marginal means for factor `b`. If you restructure your analysis to appear as a one-way ANOVA, that should be straight forward.

Comment: Okay, if I understand correctly it would be something like /contrast(Info)=special (2 -1 -1) for Control vs. Other, and /contrast(Info)=special (0 1 -1) for Moderate vs. Extreme. I don't see how to do it with 2050 vs. 2100 though, which is the main contrast I'm worried about with regard to the Control group introducing unnecessary noise. I'll keep looking.

Comment: After some looking, I found [this](http://ssc.utexas.edu/software/faqs/spss#SPSS_22) web site, which appears to explain how to create contrasts in the way you describe in your post.

Comment: Finally, an important related question: What if the overall ANOVA doesn't come out significant? For one DV, it is trending that way but not significant -- yet the Moderate vs. Extreme contrast is significant. How do I account for the noise in the overall ANOVA introduced by the Control group?